# using a verb after the word help

Tags: word-usage, catenative-verbs

I was reading a book about programming language and saw this sentence :

> ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core will retain the word
> Core to help differentiate from older legacy versions of those technologies,

So my question is, what does it mean by: "to help" + "differentiate from older legacy versions of those technologies"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word was omitted...

> ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core will retain the word Core to help differentiate **them** from older legacy versions of those technologies,

The difference is between "ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core" and older legesy versions.

Comment: That was a really good answer. Thanks

Comment: I think this just qualifies as elision [though I'm as far from an expert on this as is imaginable;) - I'd consider the full version to be "to help to differentiate them"- which  is a bit of a mouthful. The sentence reads perfectly well without the additional words.